# IEntity* wLocalEntity pointer example code snipet

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

what does this C++ code snippet do?

```
IEntity* wLocalEntity= const_cast<IEntity*>(BaseSimSystem::getEntityRef());
if(wLocalEntity!=0){
    mEntitySpeed=wLocalEntity->getSpeed();
}
```

I'm not sure how it's related to a template creation. Can someone explain to me what this code does?
Thank you.

Comment: What is `const_char` supposed to be? Is that supposed to be a `const_cast`?

Comment: I suspect there are typos in this question.  Aside from `const_char`, `getSpeed()` seems to be missing a `;`.

Comment: `if(wLocalEntity!=0)` would be better worded as `if(wLocalEntity!=nullptr)` to make the intent staggeringly obvious to everyone or as `if(wLocalEntity)` which is seen by modestly experienced programmers as *If there is a `wLocalEntity`* Comparing a pointer to a number... That's just bad code.

Comment: yea i meant const_cast

Comment: A lot of this code can not be explained.  The definitions of those types and functions would be needed, which we can not see.  The same goes for whether templates are involved in any way.

Comment: I know, but i am revieweing this code snipet for a potential job interview. It doesnt have any other explanations or additional function definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code.

```
IEntity* wLocalEntity= const_cast<IEntity*>(BaseSimSystem::getEntityRef());
if(wLocalEntity!=0){
    mEntitySpeed=wLocalEntity->getSpeed();
}
```

If you actually get asked about this code, the first thing I'd do is complain about the if-clause. that 0 should be nullptr as so:

```
if (wLocalEntity != nullptr) {
    mEntitySpeed = wLocalEntity->getSpeed();
}
```

Also, please tell me you know you shouldn't compress your code so tightly. Bugs hide when you shove all those operators together with no whitespace.

Now, let's look at line 1:

```
IEntity* wLocalEntity = const_cast<IEntity*>(BaseSimSystem::getEntityRef());
```

Clearly, wLocalEntity is a pointer to an IEntity. I hope you understood that.

The `const_cast<>` bit is ridiculous and possibly a bug. We don't know what BaseSimSystem::getEntityRef() returns, but I suspect it returns a const pointer, and now you're trying to assign that back to a non-const variable. The const_cast<> is getting rid of the constness.

The correct code is almost certainly:

```
const IEntity * wLocalEntity = BaseSimSystem::getEntityRef();
```

However, it's possible that IEntity has methods that aren't flag const that really should be, so you might have to do this because some other programmer didn't apply const when he should have.

So the `const_cast<IEntity *>` says "take the return value in those parenthesis and yes, I know they're not a non-const IEntity *, but don't warn me about it because supposedly I know what I'm doing.

How's that?

Comment: thanks for these explanations thats the top answer